# Get date of first day of 'Week/Year' format in Ruby. where week starts from Saturday

Tags: date, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3.1

Is there an in build function to extract the date of the first day from "week/year" format in rails where weeks start on Saturday.

example: `"01/2020"` should give `Sat, 04 Jan 2020`

We can get the same for the weeks that starts with Monday.

`Date.strptime("01/2020", "%V/%G")` gives `Mon, 30 Dec 2019`